Java Sorting of array
Can I sort an array based on second arrray?
I mean, lets say
a[]=[2,5,4,3]
c[]=[800,1600,200,400]

c[i] and a[i] are related for same i.
I want to sort a such that a[]=[5,2,3,4] in decreasing order of values stored in c because 5->1600 , 2->800 and so on.
Can it be done in a single line, like below (below is just structure of answer I am expecting)
Arrays.sort(a, (i, j) -> Integer.compare(c[j], c[i]))

I am doing it via lengthy method of using extra space.

yeap: but first array must be an Integer wrapper for it to work Arrays.sort(a, (i, j) -> Integer.compare(c[Arrays.asList(a).indexOf(j)], c[Arrays.asList(a).indexOf(i)])); If that is acceptable let me know, I can add it as an answer

@JorgeCampos wouldn't this approach not work for duplicate values?

If c[i] and a[i] are related, then why don't you create a class or record for it? Example: record Employee(int id, int salary) {}.

I'm pretty certain you can achieve this in one line with IntStream shenanigans.  It'll be a long and awkward line, more difficult to understand and probably less efficient than a more explicit solution -- like most applications of streams that aren't aimed at one of the "sweet spots" of the API.

@dani-vta you are definitely correct, did not take that into account, would need a few more tricks in there.

This question is similar to: Sorting two arrays simultaneously. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

After some shenanigans with IntStream here is a one liner solution taking into account duplicates: int[] result = new int[4]; result = IntStream.range(0, a.length).boxed().sorted((i, j) -> Integer.compare(c[j], c[i])).map(i -> a[i]).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();

Anti-pattern: parallel collections
